# jquery regex replace href

Tags: jquery, regex, string, dom-manipulation, html

I have this structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="mydomain/site/location/paris/">Paris</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="mydomain/site/location/london/">London</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="mydomain/site/location/amsterdam-and-paris/">Amsterdam and Paris</a></li>
</ul>
```

and i need to replace href of each anchor with this:

```
<a href="mydomain/site/event?location=london">London</a>
```

Can you help me please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`.attr()` has a form](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex-%20attr) when you can use a callback function to transform the currently set attribute.

Using it and combining with the right regex something like this would work:

```
$("a[href^='mydomain/site']").attr('href', function (i, attr) {
    return attr.replace(
        /^(mydomain\/site\/)(location)\/([^/]*)\//
        , '$1event?$2=$3'
    );
})​
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/tBkrU/)
- [Regex - Learn about Javascript Regexp](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) - it's unavoidable
- [Regexr - Great tool to try out your regexes](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)
- [Javascript - String.replace() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [jQuery - Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: tnx for the guides, I appreciate it